# Animate View properties by moving other sibling views

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I am trying to create an iOS UI where I have a set of subviews arranged as a grid on the UI and on clicking any of them I would like to expand this subview to a larger size. I am able to do the animation to expand this subview but I would also like this functionality such that other subviews nearby are pushed away.

On dimissing, this expanded view it should contract to the original size and bring back the other views to its original location.

I am thinking of a variety of ways to implement this but there are many use cases, and hence I would like some pointers in the right direction?

Does iOS itself provide a functionality by which expanding a sibling view contracts/moves the neighboring one? If not, what other ways are there to implement this?

Toms

Comment: That depends on the way you've implemented your grid. Does it allow elements with different sizes?